# Composition of disjoint cycles

Tags: functions

My question is : how can we show that a bijection on a finite set is a composition of disjoint cycles ?

I'm thinking maybe we should map every cycles to another finite set or something ? Or can we use relations ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let the finite set be $S$, and let $f:S\to S$ be a bijection. Fix any $x_0\in S$. Given $x_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. $S$ is finite, so there must be some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_m=x_n$ for some $n<m$, and we may assume that $m$ is minimal with this property.

- Show that $\{x_k:n\le k<m\}$ is a cycle.
- Let $T=S\setminus\{x_k:n\le k<m\}$, and show that $f\upharpoonright T$ is a bijection from $T$ to $T$.

Now apply induction.

Comment: I think I understand the idea, but not how to write the proof !

Comment: @Théodore: Set it up as a strong induction on $|S|$. The case $|S|=1$ is trivial. I pretty much showed you how to organize the induction step; you really just have to fill in the details for the two bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

Define the set $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$. You have a bijection $f:A\to A$.
Now, Consider $a_1$ and construct the set $A_1=\{a_1,f(a_1),f(f(a_1)),...\}$, where the set 'ends' when $f(...f(a_1)...)=a_1$. If $A=A_1$, the cycle is $a_1f(a_1)...$, if not, construct the set $A_2$ like $A_1$ but with the first $a_i$ that is not in $A_1$.

If you have constructed $A_1,...,A_j$ (that are disjoit) and $A=A_1\cup...\cup A_j$, you have the cycles.

For example, if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $f(1)=3,f(2)=4,f(3)=5,f(4)=2,f(5)=1,f(6)=6$, you have $A_1=\{1,3,5\},A_2=\{2,4\},A_3=\{6\}$ and $f=(135)(24)(6)$

Comment: Okay but how do I know it is the cycle ? Also the cycle seems to infinite which doesn't make sense since a cycle is a subset of our original set (where the bijection is defined) which we said is finite.

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg i edited